# How to split a large table in Teradata

Tags: partitioning, table, teradata

I'm trying to load data from a very large table (200 million rows) into a Presentation Datamart (PDM) for an Enterprise Data Warehouse using Teradata 14.10. I want to split this large table into several separate tables containing 30 million rows each.

I've simplified things down, but here's the table structure:

```
CREATE SET TABLE MYDB.LARGE_TABLE ,NO FALLBACK ,
    NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
    NO AFTER JOURNAL,
    CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
(
    CUSTOMERID INTEGER TITLE 'CUSTOMER IDENTIFIER' NOT NULL
    , FULLNAME VARCHAR(30) NOT CASESPECIFIC TITLE 'FULLNAME'
);
```

I've gotten as far as using ROW_NUMBER() so I know how many actual rows there are in the table:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMERID, ORDER BY CUSTOMERID) AS RANK_CUST
    , CUSTOMERID
    , FULLNAME
FROM
    MYDB.LARGE_TABLE AS MYTBL
```

Because of the SQL standards that are enforced we have to follow these restrictions:

- Cannot use Stored Procedures
- No single piece of code to contain more than 3 table joins
- No single piece of code to result in more than 30 million rows of output

I'm preparing this SQL script for a very stringent review, and it definitely won't be approved unless I can find a way to split this large table into smaller rows of data. With these restrictions in mind, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: *"No single piece of code to contain more than 3 table joins"* Why?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the QUALIFY statement to restrict the number of rows against a large table.

```
SELECT CUSTOMERID
     , FULLNAME
  FROM MYDB.LARGE_TABLE AS MYTBL
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CUSTOMERID) 
        BETWEEN 1 and 30000000;
```

**edit - corrected syntax of ROW_NUMBER()**

Comment: There should be no comma before `ORDER BY`. But that's just a syntax issue, actually you shouldn't have a `PARTITION BY` clause there at all, because the restriction is simply "no more 30 million rows" rather than "no more 30 million rows per CUSTOMERID".

Comment: You're right. I took the OP's SQL and moved tit to the qualify without careful consideration for the syntax.